# Bluemix SSO - Some users loose their access

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I've got a Java Bluemix application configured with the SSO Service connected with a SAML 2.0 and a Cloud Directory. 
The SAML Enterprise works correctly in general, but some users have got the following problem during the SSO redirection and they can not access anymore:

```
FBTSML238E The SAML message signature could not be validated.
    Time:2015-10-29T21:18:57Z
    Request address:/mtfim/sps/idaas/saml20/login
    Error details:FBTLIB103E The received message failed signature verification: FBTKJK039E The SignedInfo signature value does not match the calculated value..
```

Did you have any of these problems in the past ? Do you have any suggestion to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: There was a problem at the SSO Provider side, the administrator fixed it (It included the use of SHA1 for the signature). The SAML access is working normally now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem at the SSO Provider side, the administrator fixed it (It included the use of SHA1 for the signature). 
The SAML access is working normally now.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with this error the last days of October, but it that was resolved. If you keep on seeing the problem please open a ticket to Bluemix support.